# nightWatch resizeWindow sets different values on different browsers

Tags: selenium, window-resize, nightwatch.js

```
module.exports = {
    "resizeWindow" : function (browser) {
        browser
            .url("about:blank")
            .waitForElementVisible("body", 1)
            .resizeWindow(960, 600)
            .execute(function(){
                alert(document.body.clientWidth);
            })
    }
};
```

alert values:
internet explorer: 944
chrome: 944
firfefox: 946

It could at least all be the same

I also opened an issue on github: https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/issues/377

any ideas ? :)

**edit:**

I found the problem is that selenium sets browser window width which unless maximized, has its frame and browser body width is always narrower than window width.

[image]

Any ideas how to set browser body width, not window width ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the difference between the window width and body width, you could write a custom command which takes the browser as an argument and resizes it based on the current browser environment.

I.e

```
exports.command = function() {
    var browserName = this.options.desiredCapabilities.browserName;

    if (browserName === 'firefox') {
      this
        .resizeWindow(974, 600)
    }
  // allows command to be chained
  return this;
};
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it should work. Add whatever other browsers you need, with the correct `width + browserWidthOffset`, and simply call it at the beginning of each test.

Comment: Even better, you could put this into a `beforeEach()` function exported from your globals file, and then every test you write would always resize correctly, based on the browser.